# media query is overwriting the previous rule - resizing issue

Tags: css, resize, media-queries

I'm trying to fix a responsive design for a website, starting from mobile, to tablet then desktop.

The Mobile works fine (when I inspect by the console, or just by checking in mobile devices- like samsung j7,s5 or iphone 6,7..), also Responsive checks out perfect.

But, the resizing of the desktop screen does not work at all.

If I inspect the Website with Chrom devtools, I see that all the rules are getting over written by the last media query, no matter what is the real **size** of the screen.

This is my code :

```
/*Mobile Devices*/
 @media (min-device-width:290px) and (max-device-width: 479px){}

/*Desktop Resizing - Small*/
 @media (min-width: 290px) and (max-width: 479px) {}

/*Tablet Devices*/
  @media (min-device-width:480px) and (max-device-width: 899px){}


/*Desktop Resizing - Medium*/
  @media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 899px){}

/*Desktop - Large*/
 @media only screen and (min-width:900px){}
```

Comment: where is your html? do you have this in the head section? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: easier then i thought. I added the line of code which I forgot to the HTML, and I changed the code of the last Query to : @media (min-width:900px){} Thanx

Comment: @mlegg, it seems that you comment solved the problem, you should repost it as the answer.